# ¿Como alinear imágenes html con css, en: varias filas y colocando en cada una de ellas, de 3 a 4 imágenes alineadas?

Tags: html5, css3, wordpress

Intento desde wordpress insertar y alinear imágenes colocando de 3 a 4 en cada fila, ejemplo:

¿Como hacerlo con CSS, y ponerle la propiedad para que se vea responsive?

```html
<img> <img> <img> <img>
  <img>  <img>  <img>
<img> <img> <img> <img>
  <img>  <img>  <img>
```

```html
<img src="http://foroam.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CMIC_Fondo-de-fondos_logo_baja.jpg" alt="" width="346" height="207" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3032" />
<img src="http://foroam.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/LOGO-MV.jpg" alt="" width="346" height="207" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3035" />
<img src="http://foroam.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Nafin_logo_1.png" alt="" width="346" height="207" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3037" />
```

Comment: men, y si los pones con medidas de porcentaje y lo combinas con min-width, ejemplo: 
`width:33%` suponiendo que quieres de a 3 por fila , y lo combinas con `min-width:200px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El truco es agregarles el atributo "`display inline`" para hacerlos en línea, y después usar porcentaje en lugar de píxeles.

Para la primera columna hacemos esta matemática:

```
100% (tamaño de la div parent) / 4 (Número de imágenes) = 25%
```

Para la segunda columna:

```
100% (tamaño de la div parent) / 3 (Número de imágenes) = 33.3%
```

---

### Todo en conjunto será así:

> ### Edición:
>
> Si desea añadir un ancho máximo, utilice `max-width`.
> (Ya implementado abajo)

```css
.imgWrapper4, .imgWrapper3 {
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.imgWrapper4 .imgResponsiva,
.imgWrapper3 .imgResponsiva {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
}
.imgWrapper4 .imgResponsiva {width: 25%; max-width: 345px;}
.imgWrapper3 .imgResponsiva {width: 33.3%; max-width: 345px;}

.imgResponsiva img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgWrapper4">
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgWrapper3">
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

> ### Nueva Edición:
>
> Para poner un espacio entre cada imagen, hace lo siguiente:
> (Haz clic en el botón de abajo <kbd>Mostrar fragmento de código</kbd> para mostrar el código) O también puede verlo aquí - https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/8j4gtbb3/1/

```css
.imgWrapper4, .imgWrapper3 {
    font-size: 0;
}
.imgWrapper4 .imgResponsiva,
.imgWrapper3 .imgResponsiva {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 10px;                  /* Cambie el valor de espaciado como desee aquí */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imgWrapper4 .imgResponsiva {width: 25%;}
.imgWrapper3 .imgResponsiva {width: 33.3%;}

.imgResponsiva img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgWrapper4">
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgWrapper3">
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife"/>
    </div>
    <div class="imgResponsiva">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: De acuerdo. Así saldría en forma de lista no? Y para que salgan en filas de 3 y 4 imagenes?: img  img img

Comment: Si! Haga clic en el botón azul `Ejecutar` debajo de todo el código para ver en acción. O puede verlo también aquí en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/8j4gtbb3/)

Comment: si, tiene razón. Pero a mi me muestra en lista hacia abajo, no se que porque,

Comment: ¡ @ArmandoArellano Imposible! Talvez es cuando transferiste el código a tu proyecto y se olvidó de cambiar algo, porque aquí funciona como un encanto y no hay razón para no hacerlo. No utilicé ninguna propiedad que haría eso ni las propiedades de CSS3 Incluso probé ahora esto en Google Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 para asegurarme de que funciona perfectamente y que ya sabía que funcionaría perfecto de todos modos.

Comment: liisto, error mio. Disculpe y ¿si quiero poner un espacio entre cada imagen para que no salgan tan juntas las imgs en la fila?

Comment: @ArmandoArellano He editado mi respuesta de nuevo para eso. Mira al final de ella.

Comment: Gracias, ¿Si quiero agregar mas filas con imagenes debó agregar un nuevo: class="imgWrapper" ?

Comment: Si `class="imgWrapper3"` O `class="imgWrapper4"` dependiendo del número de fotos que quieras mostrar `3` o `4`.

Comment: ¿puede haber más de un class="imgWrapper3" O class="imgWrapper4". Con ese mismo nombre?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que no le des un alto fijo a las imágenes; no es lo ideal porque las imágenes pueden tener un aspect ratio diferente. Algunas pueden tener un ratio `16:10/9` mientras que otras imágenes pueden ser `4:3` y si le das un ancho fijo, este ocasionará que las imágenes se vean *encogidas*, lo cual no es bueno.

En el siguiente ejemplo te muestro una manera usando con el modelo tradicional de 12 columnas y flexbox ya que, si usamos `inline-block` tendríamos que usar [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc) para restar los márgenes al ancho de las columnas.

**Ejemplo**

```js
// No necesario para el layout. Este código solo hace un lazy loading de las imágenes.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 let images = document.querySelectorAll('.grid img');
  [].forEach.call(images, function (image) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      image.src = img.src;
    }
    img.src = image.getAttribute('real-src');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500');


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.row {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 8px;
}

.row:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.col {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.col.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col.col-4 {
  width: 33.3%;
}

.col img {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 25px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #777;
  color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Images</h2>
<div class="grid" style="margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-3">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif"  real-src="http://i.imgur.com/sCqyvc8.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif"  real-src="http://i.imgur.com/mZd78P1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif"  real-src="http://i.imgur.com/4536vHc.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif"  real-src="http://i.imgur.com/uua0oYr.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-4">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif" real-src="http://i.imgur.com/82STrtI.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif" real-src="http://i.imgur.com/9jxwGfN.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f3JskPX.gif" real-src="http://i.imgur.com/TINIFjJ.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionaria editando desde wordpress? Lo que pasa es que no me esta acomodando las imagenes en filas correctamente. por ejemplo la primera imagen de la segunda fila la pone en medio de y no a la izquierda, la segunda la acomoda al ultimo y la tercera abajo de la otra fila

Comment: El código es correcto. No hay lógica para que se desborde porque las filas **no tienen** `flex-wrap: wrap` y por ende, no se puede desbordar hacia abajo. Te recomiendo pegues correctamente el código, incluyendo `box-sizing` y veas si no hay una clase css que se llame igual a las que he usado ya que puede ocasionar un conflicto.

Comment: es cierto, verificaré, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué quieres dicer que las imágenes se estiran? ¿Sabes qué `width: 100;` Y `height: auto;` ¿hace en una imagen? Esto significa que las imágenes nunca serán estiradas independientemente de su tamaño y siempre ocuparán 100% de la `div parent`. Y si el problema es que las imágenes no están centradas verticalmente compruebe este [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/8j4gtbb3/1/) y mira también donde se puede ver que las imágenes no están estiradas! Lo que usted dijo en ese comentario es una tontería!

Comment: 1. No vi con detenimiento tu código y me basé en cómo se mostraban las imágenes (todas del mismo alto). Error mío. 2. ¿Sabías qué `height: auto` **es igual a no poder nada** ya que es una propiedad **no heredable**? Aunque es cierto que su uso se puede limitar a ciertos contextos bastante particulares. 3. No te estoy faltando el respeto y te pido cordialmente que tampoco lo hagas. Ya edito mi respuesta.

Comment: ¿como se podría poner un espacio entre cada imagén? en su diseño

Comment: y, ¿como establecer un tamaño fijo en los cuadros contenedores de las imagenes @Guz? Para que aparezca tamaño diferente por cada fila de imagenes que vaya yo colocando

Comment: Si le pones una alto fijo debes cerciorarte que las imágenes tenga una dimensión cuadrada, por ejemplo 2000 x 2000, esto para que las imágenes se vean correctamente cuando bajas las dimensiones. Solo selecciona las imágenes de x fila y dales un alto fijo. Por ejemplo, las imágenes de la fila 3 deben tener un alto de 200px: `.row:nth-child(3) > .col > img { height: 200px; }`